# Is it possible to distribute enterprise/in-house tvOS apps over the air to Apple TV?

Tags: tvos, enterprise, apple-tv, in-house-distribution

iOS enterprise apps has the ability to be distributed over the web using a manifest file. Can the tvOS be distributed in a similar manner? I know there's no web browser for tvOS, but I was wondering if there's a way to airdrop a file onto the Apple TV to install an internal tvOS app?

The only way so far is to either use an MDM server or use Apple Configurator via a Mac to drag and drop an IPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testflight to distribute you App in-house creating a group of internal or even external testers.

Sadly HockeyApp or similar 3rd party distribution systems do not support tvOS yet.

Comment: Trying to avoid Testflight as it requires additional setup for each new user.

Comment: @ninjaneer Fastlane Boarding can help to mitigate the bureaucracy of Testflight https://github.com/fastlane/boarding

Comment: Good to know, but it still involves the user signing up for an Apple account on the TV (this tvOS app is meant to be used as a kiosk at a store and some users don’t have an Apple device). I’ll see if this is viable.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154727/ios-enterprise-development-testflight) says that before Apple acquired TestFlight it **was possible**, but is not anymore to distribute Enterprise-Apps InHouse.